# Angular2 - stopping 'setInterval' http requests on route change

Tags: asynchronous, angular, setinterval, observable, angular2-routing

I'm writing a realtime updating graph using Angular2. My graph is being updated through data coming via an `http` observable, and a `setInterval` command.

A weird thing I've noticed is that, when I route through angular to a different view on my app, the `setInterval` command on the previous component does not stop, causing the server for unnecessary load.

What would be the correct method to stop `setInterval` http requests on route changes in Angular2?

Any help would appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Events are managed very differently by browsers](http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval), basically they are processed by **Event loop**.

> The browser has inner loop, called **Event Loop**, which checks the queue
>   and processes events, executes functions etc.

So whenever you add any asynchronous event like `setTimeout`/`setInterval`, they gets added to **Event Loop** with their handlers.

Basically whenever you wanted to `stop/de-register` those asynchronous event, you need to de-register them manually. Like here you need to call `clearInterval` method with that `setInterval` object reference, then only it will remove that `async` event from `Event Loop`.

You could use `ngOnDestroy` life-cycle hook where you can have your stuff before destroying your component.

```
//hook gets called before Component get destroyed or you can say disposed.
ngOnDestroy(){
    clearInterval(intervalReference)
}
```

---

**Extra stuff(Comparing with Angular 1)**

The same kind of problem you can see in any Javascript Framework. In Angular 1 there is way to handle such kind of situation(I'm adding this stuff so that anyone from `Angular 1` background can easily get this concept by comparing `A1` with `A2`). While destroying `controller` instance angular internally emit's `$destroy` event over `element` & `$scope` of that element. So by having listener over `$destroy` event, we used to do stuff to ensure those object `value/object/events` should not available.

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function(event){
   //do stuff here
})

element.bind('$destroy', function(event){
   //do stuff here
})
```